# How does the Quaking Enhancement interacts with Feats?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat-maneuver

**Quaking (Weapon Master's Handbook pg. 30)**

> This special ability can be placed only on melee bludgeoning weapons.
>   The wielder of a quaking weapon **can strike the ground as a standard
>   action to perform a trip combat maneuver** that applies to all foes
>   within a 5-foot-radius spread, a 10-foot cone, or a 20-foot line along
>   the ground. The wielder can trip creatures of any size this way. This
>   trip maneuver attempt provokes attacks of opportunity unless the
>   wielder has some feat or ability that prevents it, and the wielder can
>   never be knocked prone as a result of failing this special trip combat
>   maneuver check.

Emphasis mine.

Le't say that Bob the Brawler has a magic Mace, with the Quaking Enhancement. He also has, Dexterity 20, Combat Reflexes (for a total of 6 AoO per round), Greater Trip and Vicious Stomp (with all their pre-requisites).

Now, let's assume Bob the Brawler is surrounded by 8 enemies!

The question: Does quaking trigger Greater Trip? Allowing Bob and his allies to make AoO against those enemies, or only Bob's Vicious Stomp would be triggered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You get to apply the normal benefit of trip-related feats/abilities you have when you use the *Quaking* power.**

Functionally, the weapon enables you to make a special trip combat manoeuvre which has different targeting (allowing you to effect all targets in a given area and targets of any size) and negates the counter-trip possibility, but is in all other respects a normal trip attempt. It even specifically clarifies that you'd normally provoke an AoO despite this being a special weapon power, unless you've got a feat/ability which prevents that - so it follows that any other trip-related abilities you have can be applied to this trip attempt too. You would make your check including the bonus from Improved Trip/Greater Trip, you don't provoke AoOs, and your enemies will provoke AoOs from Greater Trip if you successfully trip them.